# How to use AWS session manager port forwarding to connect to RDS instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-session-manager

I am new to `AWS` Session manager. And my requirement is as follows.

I have a `RDS` instance I need to connect to. Currently it is not publicly accessible. I am using VPN to connect to it.

Since I heard about AWS session manager with `port forwarding` feature, I need to use it to connect to my RDS instance from the local machine for local development.

How can I do this? When I read through the documentation, I can only connect to the `EC2` instance using session manager, how can I achieve this to connect to my rds from local with port forwarding?